# PowerShell - Set-RemoteMailbox to move to Office365 - object couldn't be found

Tags: exchange, powershell, exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I'm trying to create an online mailbox for existing Exchange 2010 user. This user is present in AD for sure. To do this I'm trying to use command like:

Set-RemoteMailbox 'userE-mail'

Though, I'm getting error saying:

**The operation couldn't be performed because object 'userE-mail' couldn't be found on 'DC.domain.local'.**

I have read documentation about this cmdlet multiple times and have used either user e-mail and their samaccountname, name, GUID. I have also tried this doing on 2 different domains - the production one (where could be some restrictions) and the local one (without restrictions).

I'm running this command having established connection to Exchange via PowerShell (/powershell) and also tried to execute this command via EMS console.

Result is the same. Searching on web didn't bring any visible results.
May be some of you have faced such problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### From Exchange Management Shell:

If the mailbox **does not exist** on-premises nor in O365, then you need to use `Enable-RemoteMailbox` instead. Run this against an existing AD object on-prem. Technet reference: [Enable-RemoteMailbox (EX2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff607313(v=exchg.141).aspx)

If the mailbox **exists** on-premises and you need to move it to the Cloud, use `New-MoveRequest`. This is a cross-forest move, so make sure you are familiar.  Technet reference: [New-MoveRequest (EX2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351123(v=exchg.141).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
Can you tell if this command is supposed to be run inside Exchange connection session (for example in EMS)? 
As well as if i run it inside of EMS (2010) it says that:
The term 'New-RemoteMailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: My bad, You have to provision a mailbox and migrate it up with EX 2010 on-premises.

Comment: You don't have to migrate.  This answer is correct. When you run enable-rmeotemailbox it will create the properties needed for an EXISTING AD object to get a cloud mailbox.  You then sync the account and assign a license and a mailbox is created correctly for the Hybrid setup.  New-RemoteMailbox is used to create a NEW AD Object with the proper properties set for creating the mailbox.  Again requiring a sync and license assignment in O365.